# anime stagger out of order?

Tags: javascript, animation, anime.js

This is what I use for an animation at the end in a online connect 4 game:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 4; i ++){
                    var circle = document.getElementById(winAnimDivIDs[i]);
                    circle.classList.add("finishAnim");
                }
                anime({
                    targets: '.finishAnim',
                    scale: [
                        {value: 1.2, duration: 400},
                        {value: 1, duration: 500}
                    ],
                    delay: anime.stagger(500, {easing: 'easeOutElastic'}),
                    loop: true
                });
            }
```

What is the Order In which they'll get animated and how to define it? cause If I put it like this the coin to the most left gets animated first, then there's a delay and then all other 3 coins will pop up... Im aware you might need some more code, but this part of a 680 LOC client code (all written by me) and I did not want to put it all here..

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the delay value in each loop. Currently, the loop will complete and they will all receive the same delay value which is why they all animate at the same time.

Add value to add to your 500ms delay in `anime.stagger(500, {easing: 'easeOutElastic'})`

Snippet to demo a simple example:

```js
const delay = 100;
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.info(`yo, ${i}`);
  }, delay * i);
}
```